# Is it possible to achieve ToString Override method

Tags: .net, vb.net, tostring

Is there any way I can add a method to `.ToString`?  If not all `.ToString`, then more specifically:

```
For Each Client as DataRow in DT.Rows
    Msgbox(Client.Item("first_name").ToString.**ProperCase**)
Next
```

I want to add a `.ProperCase` to `ToString`.  `StrConv(Client.Item("first_name").tostring`, `vbProperCase)`

Is this possible?

Comment: Search for "Extension Methods VB.NET".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToString is a method. So you can't add a method to it, but you can add a method to one of the classes.

You can write extension methods on the System.String class or the System.Object class. You can also **overload builtin methods as long as the signature differs**. You can't write a new ToString() but you can write a ToString(bool) to differentiate it.

A few alternatives:

1. Create an enum type that has a value ProperCase and write an overloaded extension method `ToString(ToStringOpts)` on System.Object:

   ```
   Client.Item("first_name").ToString(ProperCase)
   ```
2. Extension method `ProperCase()` on System.String to be chained (fluent syntax):

   ```
   Client.Item("first_name").ToString.ProperCase()
   ```
3. Extension method `ToStringProperCase()` on System.Object so you just need one method call:

   ```
   Client.Item("first_name").ToStringProperCase()
   ```

Extension method documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

I'm a C# guy, so VB.NET guys help me out here, but the general idea is:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToStringProperCase(ByVal s As String) As String
     Return String.Concat(s.Substring(0,1).ToUpper(), s.Substring(1).ToLower())
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ran into issues, the project I am working on is using 2.0.  While googling shows ways of doing so in 2.0, it breaks other things with my project.  But now I know how to do it with my other projects that use 4.0.  Thanks for the explanation and samples.